# Building Android NDK Toolchain for x86 Android on Windows via Cygwin

Tags: android, gcc, cygwin, x86, android-ndk

The Android SDK includes the Android NDK, which in turn contains a customised GCC based tool chain for Android on ARM processors; The question is how to build the NDK tool chain to run on Windows to target x86 Android?

The tool chain is already setup to build on Windows (cygwin) targeting ARM;
There are also existing [pre-built (unofficial) NDKs](http://www.android-x86.org/download) for targeting x86, but these contain pre-built tools for x86 Linux, not Windows.

The NDK contains a build-toolchain.sh script to rebuild its tool chain; the question is, what specifically needs done to get that to build a tool chain targeting Android x86?

Comment: not sure but there are members on the android-ndk google groups list that might know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of NDK r6, Google supply x86 support themselves.

> Adds support for the x86 ABI, which allows you to generate machine code that runs on compatible x86-based Android devices. Major features for x86 include x86-specific toolchains, system headers, libraries and debugging support. For all of the details regarding x86 support, see docs/CPU-X86.html in the NDK package.

[NDK Release Notes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html)